# Finding closed form of recurrence relation in two variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences

I have a recurrence,
$$F(n, m) = F(n-1, m) + F(n, m-1) + F(n-1,m-1) $$

$$F(n,1)  = 0$$
$$F(1,n)  = 2*(n-1)$$

I would like to compute $F(N,M)$ in terms of $N$ and $M$. The system is defined for $1 \leq n \leq N$ and $1 \leq m \leq M$ where $N$ and $M$ are non-negative integers.
I have solved many linear recurrences in past, but this type of recurrence in two variables is new to me. I even researched but couldn't find any good research paper involving method of reducing recurrences in terms of variables.

The value of $N$ can be upto $10^3$ and value of $M$ is upto $10^9$.

Comment: Posted also on Mathematics: [Solving recurrence equation in two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2950321). [This answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se#2638) gives, in my opinion, a very reasonable advice about cross-posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F(n,m)=D(n,m-1)-D(n-1,m-1)$ where $D(n,m)$ are the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number).

Comment: I wouldn't call this formula "closed form", but it shifts to the problem to a well known object.

Comment: Hi, I went through link, and find it useful. but n can be upto 1e9, how can i calcaulate nCk for that ?

Comment: Notice that $D(n,m-1)-D(n-1,m-1)=D(n,m-2)+D(n-1,m-2)$. The size of the latter for $n=10^3, m=10^9$ can be estimated to be of the order of 6500 digits. So it depends on what you mean by "calculate". If you want all the digits of a specific value in your range, the formula $D(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{k=\min(m,n)} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} 2^k$ seems to me within easy reach of a laptop, with the right package and smart program.

Comment: @J.Jack : In terms of calculating $\binom{m}{k}$ for $1\le m \le 10^9$ and $1\le k \le 1^3$ if would simply do $(m-k+1)/1\times(m-k+2)/2\times(m-k+3)/3\times\cdots$, if there is nothing else better.

Comment: since I need to calculate D(n, m-1) and D(n-1, m-1), I would have to calculate (m-1)Ck, and order of m is upto 10^9 and k can be atmost 10^3. Can you tell how can I efficiently compute mCk using this? A simple "for loop in C++" running for 1e9, won't it be unoptimized approach? Edit : This comment was made before seeing your recent comment.

Comment: what would be Complexity in that case for calculation of mCk ?

Comment: Not my expertise, but we are talking for $D(n,m)$, $n<m$,  of $O(n^2)$ products and divisions of numbers up to $\log_{10}(m)\times n$ digits, and $O(n)$ sums...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yaakov Baruch, for your help. It indeed help me a lot. Thanks once again.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you find that the given recurrence relation can be expressed in terms of Delannoy numbers. I am asking because I had done lot of struggle to find closed form recurrence through OEIS and Wolframalpha but I couldn't succeed. Because at the end what matters is intuition of getting to answer and not the actual answer.

Comment: @J.Jack Sure. I built a few terms based on the recurrence relation, but starting from a single $1$ at the apex, then looked up the central terms on OEIS and found the reference to Delannoy numbers, which satisfy your recurrence. Eyeballing the table at wikipedia it was clear that subtracting from the table a shifted one, would keep the recurrence while also meeting your initial conditions.

Comment: I would say that the rationale for starting with just $1$ at the apex is that it is sort of like studying the homogeneous problem, hoping to somehow handle the initial conditions later.